# Child div not responding to parent's relative property

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to to create two divisions. Basically two 50% divs next to each other. I am attempting to center the divs vertically and I usually use this block of code to center things vertically/horizontally:

```
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

However, in this case it seems that my child divs `green-grid-left` and `green-grid-right` are not responding to the `position: relative` of `green`.

Can anyone tell me why my two divs are not aligning in the middle of each of their 50% blocks?

```css
.green {
 background-color: rgb(69,186,149); /*--Maybe this    background: #00a16d; ---*/
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
}
#green-grid-left {
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 /*text-align: center;
 margin: auto;*/
 width: 50%;
 height: 90%;
 float: left;
}
#green-grid-left-description {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2.3em;
}
#green-grid-right {
 width: 50%;
 height: 90%;
 float: right;
}
#green-grid-right-description {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <div id="green-grid-left">
   <div id="green-grid-left-description">Website problems?<br>
   We handle everything for you.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="green-grid-right">
   <div id="green-grid-right-description">Website problems?<br>
   We handle everything for you.</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: May i use bootsrap? is it fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so much easier with flexbox:

```css
.green {
  background-color: rgb(69, 186, 149);
  /*--Maybe this    background: #00a16d; ---*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.green > div {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
#green-grid-left-description {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2.3em;
}
#green-grid-right-description {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <div id="green-grid-left-description">Website problems?
    <br>We handle everything for you.</div>

  <div id="green-grid-right-description">Website problems?
    <br>We handle everything for you.</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to position the elements absolute. Position them relative and only align them vertically. You don't actually want them to be horizontally centered. Use margin for that
https://jsfiddle.net/3tejdtq5/

```
<div class="parrent">
<div class="left child"></div>
<div class="right child"></div>
</div>

div{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parrent{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0;
}

.child{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%,-50%);
  width: 35%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left{
  margin: 0 5% 0 10%; 
}

.right{
  margin: 0 10% 0 5%;
}
```

or something better

```
<div class="parrent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parrent{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.child{
  width: 35%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t9e4vroo/

Answer (score 1):

If you set an absolute position with a top property to 50% and a translate X property to -50%, your element will be at the center in X of your parent. Because it translate in X -50% of the children width. If you want one children in the left and the other one in the right and both vertically centered, you can do it this way with absolute position and translate property :

```css
.green {
 background-color: rgb(69,186,149); /*--Maybe this    background: #00a16d; ---*/
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
}
#green-grid-left {
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 25%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 50%;
 height: 90%;
}
#green-grid-left-description {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2.3em;
}
#green-grid-right {
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 75%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 50%;
 height: 90%;
}
#green-grid-right-description {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  <div id="green-grid-left">
    <div id="green-grid-left-description">
      Website problems?<br>
      We handle everything for you.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="green-grid-right">
    <div id="green-grid-right-description">
      Website problems?<br>
      We handle everything for you.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already defined for them a position, so they will take that position you defined (absolute) and ignore the one from it's parent. If you want them to inherit the position from its parent you need to set their position to `inherit` like:

```
#green-grid-left {
    ...
    position: inherit;
    ...
}

#green-grid-right {
    ...
    position: inherit;
    ...
}
```

Position is not inherit by default, so you need to set it, if you want inheritance. Check [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Comment: Anytime I have ever used the code block I mentioned in my question, I have always set the parent to relative and the child to absolute, so that the child is absolutely placed in the center of the parent.